# GEKKO - General - custom reusable flowsheet object - chemical process flowsheet modelling

Tags: gekko

No problems to speak of and nor am I currently a user. I am seeing advice on the best implementation practice for flowsheet models. Is there a framework to create custom flowsheet objects in GEKKO/chemical? Is the flowsheet module a mature and equal feature of GEKKO?

I am dealing with a number of applications which would benefit from the ability to inherit flowsheet objects from a yet to be developed custom library, if possible. One such item could be a tubular reactor as described here where it is solved in COMSOL ([http://umich.edu/~elements/5e/web_mod/radialeffects/unsteady/index1.htm](http://umich.edu/%7Eelements/5e/web_mod/radialeffects/unsteady/index1.htm)). Scenarios could involve several unit operations connected in series with recycle streams such as mixer settlers in solvent extraction which also has multiple liquid phases (organic and aqueous). It is worth nothing that all of the models would be of the unsteady state type.

I appreciate the thoughts of the user group in this respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gekko doesn't currently allow black-box models where the equations are not available for requesting information such as first and second derivatives in sparse form. For that reason, a model in COMSOL wouldn't be a good fit for Gekko. If you would like to try to model the same PDE in Gekko, that is a possibility. Here are some PDE applications that may help give you inspiration:

- [Solid Oxide Fuel Cell](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/SolidOxideFuelCell)
- [Parabolic and Hyperbolic PDEs](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/PartialDifferentialEquations) Solved with Gekko

[image: PDE solved with Gekko]

[The Chemicals library](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chemical.html) is somewhat limited but it does have some thermodynamic data and basic reactor types. You could put many lumped parameter reactors in series to emulate a Plug Flow Reactor but it may be better to just write out the PDE equations. You may want to write out your own equations instead of relying on the Chemicals library.

Comment: Thanks, John. I expected as much but it is good to hear it from the source. Are there any groups you are aware of they would undertake commercial consulting services employing Gekko? I am familiar with the commercial offering from Process Systems Enterprise using their gPROMS but from a transferability and vendor lock-in perspective I would prefer an open source solution.

Comment: There are a couple companies offering consulting services with Gekko. I also have a company with a few employees.